# Copy data from one workbook to another a zillion times

Tags: excel, vba

So basically I'm entering data from one file to another in excel, but the thing is that these files look nothing alike and the cell that I'm pasting to is not specific like last row or etc. and I do it a lot of times. Because of that, I was thinking of selecting the destination cell in the dest worksheet to be the activecell and then going to the source file and after selecting the cell that needs to be copied, run the macro and the paste would be done to the dest sheet activecell but I can't seem to find a code that does this.
I'd welcome if someone has a better way, and btw I think user forms are not the best option because of the complexity of the dest file.

Thank you in advance

**Here's the code: (AA is the destination sheet name)**

```
Sub dataentry()

ActiveCell.Copy

Workbooks("AA.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

ActiveCell.Paste


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know the name of the `Source Workbook and Worksheet`? Are both workbooks open? Is the code in the `Source` or in the `Destionation Workbook`? Do you maybe have one column in mind for the `Destination` i.e. first available cell in it? If you don't know the name of the `Source Workbook and Worksheet`, then at least you have to make sure that these are the only workbooks that are open. Otherwise you will have to do `CRTL+C` before you select the `Destionation Worksheet` again.

Comment: I prefer the source workbook name to be undefined and set the code in a way to reference to the active sheet, because I use several workbooks as source and not a single specific one. The source and destination cells do not follow a logical order. Do you think necessarily only the source and destination workbook should be open?

Answer (score 0):

### Copy from Selection to Selection

- The following requires **exactly** two 'visible' workbooks to be open.
- The code is to be copied to a standard module (e.g. `Module1`) in `Destination Workbook` i.e. `ThisWorkbook`.
- Select the range in `Source Worksheet`. Select the cell in `Destination Worksheet`, if not already, and run the code preferably via a `button` or a `command button` on `Destination Worksheet`.
- The second procedure could be used for another `button` or `command button` on `Destination Worksheet` to select (activate) the `Source Worksheet`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyRangeToThisWorkbook()

    ' Define Source Range ('src').
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim src As Range
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If Not wb Is ThisWorkbook And wb.Windows(1).Visible Then
            If TypeName(wb.Windows(1).Selection) = "Range" Then
                Set src = wb.Windows(1).Selection
                Exit For
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next wb
    
    ' Define Destination First Cell ('dest').
    With ThisWorkbook.Windows(1)
        If TypeName(.Selection) = "Range" Then
            Dim dest As Range
            Set dest = .Selection.Cells(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
        
    ' Write values from Source Range to Destination Range.
    If Not src Is Nothing Then
        dest.Resize(src.Rows.Count, src.Columns.Count).Value = src.Value
    End If

End Sub

Sub activateNotThisWorkbook()
    
    ' Activate the first 'visible' workbook that is not 'ThisWorkbook'.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If Not wb Is ThisWorkbook And wb.Windows(1).Visible Then
            wb.Activate
        End If
    Next wb

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's awesome, but do you think there's a way to copy the code to the personal macro workbook and just change the destination workbook address each time in VBE?